# Way to archive r instal for model/analysis version control

Tags: r, version-control

I have been using version control (Git) to keep track of my different projects. However, due to the quick development of many r libraries, in the few times I had to revisit past analyses >1 year old the gradual updates in R libraries often mean my past analyses will not work properly.
I have been looking for a way to archive my r instal at least for important milestones of my projects (e.g., final analysis for publication) so I can theoretically always go back to them if necessary no matter how long ago I have completed the analysis and independent of subsequent R program and library updates.
Is this at all possible? What are the alternatives? How to do this without manually downloading and keeping a folder of all install packages for each necessary library and R version?

Comment: Rbloggers wrote an article about how to install and cite older packages, maybe it helps: http://www.r-bloggers.com/installoldpackages-a-repmis-command-for-installing-old-r-package-versions/

Comment: Thanks for the link- sound like this could help!